# Trouble parsing JSON with Google Scripts

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Scripts to parse some JSON and it's not working...

Here's my pseudo-code:

```
function fetchInsta() {
  var url = "xxx";
  Logger.log(url);
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json  = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var existingids = sheet.getRange("D:D");

  for(i in json.data){
    for(j in existingids){
      if(json.data[i].id = existingids[i]){
        var match = true;
      }
    }

    if(match != true){
      var id = json.data[i].id;
      var image = json.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url;
      var username = json.data[i].user.username;
      var link = json.data[i].link;      
      var date = json.data[i].createdtime;

      sheet.appendRow([image,username,link,id,date]);
      Logger.log([image,username,link,id,date]);
    }  
  }



}
```

I've removed the URL as it has my API key in it. But here's a sample of the JSON returned:

```
  "data":[  
      {  
         "attribution":null,
         "tags":[  ],
         "type":"image",
         "location":{  },
         "comments":{  },
         "filter":"Normal",
         "created_time":"1430751422",
         "link":"https:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/2Q6AiIG4hT\/",
         "likes":{  },
         "images":{  },
         "users_in_photo":[  ],
         "caption":{  },
         "user_has_liked":false,
         "id":"977536242480285779_10266761",
         "user":{  }
      },
```

I'm getting the variables image, username, link fine - but id and date are both undefined. Any ideas what's happening? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
if(json.data[i].id = existingids[i]){
```

Is using an assignment operator to test for equality.  Equality tests are done with double or triple equal signs.  If in doubt, use triple equal signs.

Should be:

```
if(json.data[i].id === existingids[i]){
```

Comment: wtf. You are correct so THANK YOU! However, I'm not sure why fixing that part of the code fixes the rest? Later in the code I was using Logger.log(json.data[i].id) and it wasn't working. No idea why fixing this logic statement earlier fixes the json lookup later? But either way - my code now words so thanks